# Drupal. Пропали переводы интерфейса после восстановления с резервной копии

Tags: drupal

После восстановления БД из резервной копии пропали некоторые переводы, точнее они в базе есть, но не используются. Появилась дополнительные строки внизу с урлом типа `/basket?o%5B38%5D%5B5719%5D=1`.
 Когда я перевожу эти строки, то нормально. Пример на картинке.

Как вернуть обратно? Там где увидел - перевёл, но очень часто появляются "сюрпризы"...[image: пример перевода слова Home]

Comment: Кэш пробовали сбрасывать?
В files/languages удалить файлы.

Comment: не помогает... Но если нажать кнопку удалить напротив последнего, то тогда берется нормальный перевод... сейчас думаю, как программно удалить все эти левые переводы (и хочу понять, откуда они берутся... где источник этого)

Comment: удалил из таблицы locales_source все записи, в которых в столбце location есть /basket?....  и очистил кэш - всё стало нормально... но как оно появилось и почему - непонятно...

Comment: Попробуйте удалить вообще все переводы.